# Returning to previous page without adding a URL parameter

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, http-referer

In my website I want to allow to return from 'itemY' page to 'topicX' page.
I don't want to add a get parameter:

```
mysite.com?ref=topicX
```

I'm not sure if using document.referrer is the right way.
Also 'itemX' can be reached directly from Google so it doesn't have to show the return link.

Comment: Maybe `history.back()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a form with a hidden field on the page. The value of the hidden form field would be the url of the location you want to return to. Then just check for the presence of this hidden form field using js?

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="goTo" name="goTo" value="topicX" />
</form>
```